# Docker alpine tunnel through public and private server to DB?

Tags: docker, jenkins, ssh, alpine-linux, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying, based on this Dockefile https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-inbound-agent/, to create a possibility for an ssh tunnel through public ssh server to use him as a connection to the private ssh server, which has a link to a secret database connected only to this remote private server. Everything works well until the DB port is unreachable under the Docker container after connection to the DB.

Note: This configuration works if using a regular VM Linux image or machine.

/home/jenkins/.ssh/config

```
HOST *
    ForwardAgent yes
AddressFamily inet
HOST public-server
    ForwardAgent yes
    Hostname <Public-IP>
    User ssh
    StrictHostKeyChecking=no
    UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
    IdentityFile /home/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa
    ControlPath ~/.ssh/public-server-%r@%h:%p
    ControlMaster auto
    ControlPersist 30m
HOST private-server
    ForwardAgent yes
    Hostname 172.0.0.2
    User ssh
    StrictHostKeyChecking=no
    UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
    IdentityFile /home/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa
    ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p public-server
    ControlMaster auto
    ControlPersist 30m
HOST db
    ForwardAgent yes
    TCPKeepAlive yes
    ConnectTimeout 5
    ServerAliveCountMax 10
    ServerAliveInterval 15
    Hostname private-server
    User ssh
    StrictHostKeyChecking=no
    UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
    ProxyCommand ssh -A -q public-server -W %h:%p
    IdentityFile /home/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa
    LocalForward *:13369 db:3369
    RemoteForward 13368 localhost:13368
```

Output after connection, it seems the port is open to all interfaces only to IPV4 because of the limitation of the docker to IPV6:

```
d9977c046374:~$ netstat -antp
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
TCP        0      0 0.0.0.0:13369           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      15/ssh
TCP        0      0 172.17.0.2:57560        <public-server>:22      ESTABLISHED 16/ssh
```

When trying to connect to the port is hanging, otherwise on standard VM image or desktop can connect:

```
d9977c046374:~$ telnet localhost 13369
Connected to localhost
```

What is missing?

Comment: Is your database also a container?

Comment: DB is a qemu VM.